# Vectorization of a loop in matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization, vectorization

I have a loop

```
for i = 2:K
    T(K,i) = ((4^(i-1))*T(K,i-1)-T(K-1,i-1))/(4^(i-1)-1); 
end
```

where `T` is a two dimensional matrix (first element in given row, and all elements in rows above are already there) and `K` is a scalar.
I have tried to vectorize this loop to make it faster like this:

```
i = 2:K;
T(K,i) = ((4.^(i-1)).*T(K,i-1)-T(K-1,i-1))./(4.^(i-1)-1);
```

it compiles, but it yields improper results. Can you tell me where am I making mistake?

@EDIT:
I have written this, but still the result is wrong

```
     i = 2:K;
     i2 = 1:(K-1);
     temp1 = T(K,i2)
     temp2 = T(K-1,i2)
     T(K,i) = ((4.^(i2)).*temp1-temp2)./(4.^(i2)-1);
```

Comment: your loop changes values of T as you iterate through it.

Comment: @bla so I should make some temporary variable to store original value?

Comment: @bla I have edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's re-index your loop (having fewer `i-1` expressions):

```
for i=1:K-1
  T(K,i+1) = ( 4^i*T(K,i) - T(K-1,i) ) / (4^i-1); 
end
```

Then (I'll leave out the loop for now), we can factor out `4^i/(4^i-1)`:

```
  T(K,i+1) = ( T(K,i) - T(K-1,i)/4^i ) * (4^i/(4^i-1));
```

Let's call `a(i) = (4^i/(4^i-1))`, `b(i) = - T(K-1,i)/4^i`, then expanding the first terms we get:

```
T(K,1) = T(K,1)
T(K,2) = T(K,1)*a(1)           + b(1)*a(1)
T(K,3) = T(K,1)*a(1)*a(2)      + b(1)*a(1)*a(2)      + b(2)*a(2)
T(K,4) = T(K,1)*a(1)*a(2)*a(3) + b(1)*a(1)*a(2)*a(3) + b(2)*a(2)*a(3) + b(3)*a(3)
```

Then with `c = [1, a(1), a(1)*a(2), ...] = [1, cumprod(a)]`

```
T(K,i) = (T(K,1) + (b(1)/c(1) + b(2)/c(2) + ... + b(i-1)/c(i-1) ) *  c(i)
```

So with `d = b ./ c`, `e = cumsum(d)`, summarizing all calculations:

```
i=1:K-1;
a = 4.^i./(4.^i-1);
b = -T(K-1,1:end-1) ./ 4.^i;
c = [1, cumprod(a)];
d = b ./ c(1:end-1);
e = cumsum(d);
T(K,2:K) = (T(K,1) + e) .* c(2:end);
```

To further optimize this, note that `4^14/(4^14 - 1)` equals 1, when calculated with double-precision, so actually `T(K,14:K)` could be optimized drastically -- i.e., you actually just need to calculate `a`, `c`, `1./c` up to index 13. (I'll leave that as an exercise).